# How to set up Jenkins credentials again

Tags: jenkins

After running the below command, how to set up Jenkins credentials again

sed -i 's/true</useSecurity>/false</useSecurity>/g' /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml

After running the command, how to set up Jenkins credentials again

Comment: It was true, you [set it](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/access-control/disable/#using-config-xml) to `false`. Set it back to `true`.